# Unity when does Debug.Log write to console

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to benchmark my algorithm. Sometimes it takes super long time and i would like to know where it has reached. But for some Reason Debug.log is not printing anything until the end of the update method.

I would like to see it to print text out step by step, but instead im getting all at once at the end of update cycle. Makediagram method is very slow. Depending on input can take 7-700 seconds.

```
private void Update()
{
if (i > 0) return;
int count = 16 * (int)Mathf.Pow(2, i);

    Debug.Log("New diagram");
        BowyerWatson bw = new BowyerWatson(BowyerWatson.STATE.STATE_3D, count, 0);
    Debug.Log("Points generated");
        float ctime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        bw.MakeDiagram();
        time += Time.realtimeSinceStartup - ctime;
    Debug.Log("i:" + i + " j:" + j + " time:" + (Time.realtimeSinceStartup-ctime));


    j++;
    if(j == 20)
    {
        i++;
        j = 0;
        Debug.Log(count + " points took: " + time / 20 + "s on average");
        time = 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug.Log writes immediately. The problem is that Update does not yield and wait for one task to end. What you really want here is a coroutine that yields while MakeDiagram() is running.

Or flag a boolean as true while MakeDiagram() is running and then in your Update() function, if the boolean is true, then `return`, and then flag the bool as false after MakeDiagram() has completed, to continue code execution.

Comment: Hmm... is put the make diagram into coroutine. Now i get the debug log. But still everything freezes while as the algorithm is running.

Comment: There's no way of knowing why without seeing the code for MakeDiagram() and the coroutine that calls it. You can try running the Unity Profiler and it might help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Make diagram is Bowyer-Watson algorithm. Unoptimized so O(n^2) 136 points to process. SO i know its gona be slow. Start coroutine has " while (bw.DoStep())
        {
            yield return null;
        }" This is basically MakeDIagram function. Just rewritten as coroutine.

Comment: The only other option I can think of to help speed things along is to call your MakeDiagram() function from a separate thread, or try to split processing into a few different threads if possible. The only things you CANNOT call from another thread are Unity API specific functions.

Comment: OR, and I literally just found this out myself, you can recreate the class in question in C++ and call it using "Native Plugins". See here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html